# Resize an image to fit in div

Tags: html, css

How can I resize the image to fit in the size of the div `piecemaker-container`?

```html
<div id="piecemaker-container"> 
    <div id="piecemaker">
      <img src="splash.jpg" alt="some_text"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
#piecemaker-container {
    display:block;
    height:460px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: -10px auto 40px;
    width: 960px;
    max-width:100%; 
    max-height:100%;
}
```

Something like -  ?

```css
#piecemaker {
    display:block;
    height:460px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: -10px auto 40px;
    width: 960px;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#piecemaker-container div, #piecemaker-container img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 4):

declare a css class for the img tag and just give it the same height and width as the div.Or just declare it as 100% as given

```
img { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 3):

This may sound like an overdo but if you don't want the image to be squeezed or stretched, why not re-size it proportionally, according to the size you want, before displaying? Because it is pretty much easy to re-size with PHP anyway

Hope it helps?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you set the `width` and `height` attributes of the `img`-tag?

```
<img src="splash.jpg" alt="some_text" width="960" height="460"/>
```

Comment: It's better to keep your style rules out of your HTML and in your CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#piecemaker-container").each( function(){
                var imageUrl = $(this).find('img').attr("src");
                $(this).find('img').css("visibility","hidden");
                $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')').css("background-repeat","no-repeat").css("background-size","cover").css("background-position","50% 50%");
            });
```