# Having trouble resizing image in div

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, resize

Sorry this might be a simple question (I'm just a beginner). I'm having some difficulty resizing my pictures inside my divs.  please see my below code and give me any needed feedback. Thank you.
Here is my code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("img").hide().fadeIn(3000);  
        });
        console.log("It works!!");
    </script>
    <title>Fruit!</title>
    <style>
        .box1 {
            background-size: auto, cover;
            text-align: left;
            border: solid;
        }
        .red {
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            display: block;
        }
        .box2 {
            background-size: auto, cover;
            text-align: left;
            border: solid;
        }
        .blue {
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            display: block;
        }
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            font-family: 'Tahoma' sans-serif;
            font-weight: 300;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            font-size: 80px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="box1">
        <h1> The Stawberry </h1>
        <img class="red" src="http://pngimg.com/upload/strawberry_PNG88.png">
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
        <h1> The Blueberry </h1>
        <img class="blue" src="http://www.tree-ripe.com/_images/_blueberries/blueberries2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="box3">
        <h1> The Banana </h1>
        <img class="yellow" src="http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130806064943/clubpenguin/images/7/7c/Banana_clean_sheet.png">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please provide some code ... there are may possible issues, and not one way to do what you want.

Comment: Please show what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I think someone already posted the same question. 
Here is the link: [Resize an image to fit in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636594/resize-an-image-to-fit-in-div)

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing the `width` and `height` properties to whatever you like them at, for example:

```
    #myImg {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
```

I hope this has helped!

Answer (score 0):

Use css height and width.  You can look it up on w3schools for more reference.  I've also included code on how to center it.  Seems like you'd want to do that.

```
 img { 
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
  // Below code will center it
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto:
    margin-right: auto;
   }
```